# Will restoring backup file using Akeeba Kickstart in other subdirectory, affect my current Joomla installation?

Tags: akeebabackup

I have Joomla 3.7.4 that runs in subdirectory /html/joomla374 of my webspace. Before upgrading to Joomla 3.7.5 I want to restore a recent backup file I created using latest Akeeba Backup extension. This backup shall be restored in subdirectory html/joomla375.

What I did so far:

- Upload the jpa file to the joomla375 subdirectory
- Upload kickstart.php
- Create a new database to be used for Joomla running in joomla375
  directory

My concerns:
When I execute .../joomla375/kickstart.php and choose to write files directly, **where will it write the files to?** To the root folder (i.e. html) or to the directory where the backup file resides (i.e. /html/joomla375)?

In other words: **Will extracting the backup file in /html/joomla375 somehow affect my running Joomla in /html/joomla374?**

Answer (score 3):

The kickstart.php restoration script will extract the contents of the akeeba archive to the same location where the archive file is located.

[Akeeba Kickstart documentation](https://www.akeebabackup.com/documentation/akeeba-kickstart-documentation/using-kickstart.html)